# I'm not sure where to find my flash drive

Tags: files

When I plugged in my brand new flash drive, it didn't pop up or show up in the computer tap in files.  How do I find the flash drive so I can access it and its files.  Is there something I have to do in the terminal, or is it a simple setting change.  please help.  Thanks!!

Comment: Post the output of lsblk command on your question.

Comment: what do you mean?  Sorry, I'm new to Ubuntu.

Comment: You can open a terminal by holding the CTRL and ALT keys and press the T key. A  terminal will open and you can enter the lsblk command and put the output at the bottom of your question. CTRL-SHIFT-C is the combination to copy what is highlighted in a terminal window. You can past it on a web page like the one holding your question with CONTROL-V.

Comment: I'm also having this issue. The `lsblk` command results can be seen [here](http://i.imgur.com/E325fJr.png).

Answer (score 0):

On a normal vanilla Trusty Tahr install, your system should auto-mount a USB flash device and add an Icon to the left hand tray in Unity.

You can also press super/windows key, and search for the "Files" application, which should show you all the files in the current directory, and on the left hand side show all storage devices, including any mounted USB or removable devices.

Finally, you could open a command prompt/terminal and run the command `mount` and review all of the storage devices listed. This may appear cryptic and depending on your experience level, you may not recognize the device in the list if it is there.

Usually, removable devices are mounted in the path `/media/<device name>/` or possibly `/media/<your-user-name>/<device name>`

=== Edit ====
The `Disks` utility will also display all attached storage, whether it is in a readable/writable state or not, so long as the OS recognizes it as storage.a

Comment: when I first plugged in the flash drive when I used it to install ubuntu, it was on the side on my desktop, it was also in the file app.  I formatted it with the disk app so that I could get all of the ISO files and what not off of it.  Now its no where to be found on my computer.

Comment: How did you format it? Did you use the desktop GUI and click/select Format, or did you execute a command in the terminal? It may be that you wiped the filesystem but didn't actually re-format the device with a new filesystem, in which case it won't show up normally. Run the `Disks` utility (might be called `Disk Utility`, but just enter `disk` into the Dash search box and it should give you some options. That should show you all storage devices connected, whether they have a filesystem that is usable or not.

Comment: I did that and it worked.  Thank you so much.  I can use it again.

Comment: Great, I'll add that to my official answer.

Comment: @user275186 if this solution worked for you then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

After reformatting a flash drive using the file app, it must be remounted before it can be used. Reformatting leaves it in an unmounted state. The fix:

unplug the device and plug it back in to automount the device.